# Creating associated records after new user registration with Devise and Apartment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, apartments

**Background**

I have a multi-tenant Rails application which uses the Apartment gem to switch schema depending on their subdomain when they login.  The `User` and `Account` entities are in the public schema.  All of the other related entities are in the account specific schema.

**Question**

When a new user signs up, the `User` and `Account` records are created during the initial form post (i.e., in `RegistrationsController#create`).

However, I would like to create other records at this time (e.g, a `Family` record), but the account specific schema hasn't been created yet and the context hasn't switched, so if I do something like this:

```
@resource.create_family(name: @resource.last_name)
```

The `Family` record will be incorrectly created in the public schema.

Devise lets you specify a `after_sign_up_path_for` value, so I was thinking of maybe creating a custom action in the `FamiliesController` that does the work of creating new record, but that seems kind of kludgy and non RESTful:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  # root_url(:subdomain => resource.account.subdomain)
  family_autocreate_url(:subdomain => resource.account.subdomain, :query => resource.last_name)
end
```

What's the right way to do this?

(Note: the schema context isn't switched until I redirect to a URL with the account specific subdomain. Hence the thought of doing it )

Comment: Apartment allows you to manually switch context with Apartment::Tenant.switch!('tenant_name'). What is the problem if in RegistrationsController, after an account is created, you manually switch context and create the associated family object?